# Pythagoras' Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a triangle using Latex which represents length 1 along the horizontal axis, `$\tan{\theta}$` along the vertical axis and `$\sqrt{1+ \tan^2(\theta)}$` along the hypotenuse, with angle `$\theta$` between the horizontal and the hypotenuse.

Comment: Reason for -1: probably didn't even google. https://www.google.com/search?q=pythagoras+triangle

Comment: One down vote is enough to make the point. To Kit: welcome to the site! It'd be great if you could show us what you have so far, perhaps a possible starting point from which the community can continue

Comment: This sounds like a subset of the first tutorial example "A picture for Karl's students" in the [pgfmanual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Although somewhat irrelevant now: I forgot to include "+tikz" in the hyperlink above.

Answer (score 4):

The rest is given in the manual.

```
\tikz{\def\mytheta{30}\draw (0,0) -- (\mytheta:1) |- (0,0)--cycle;}
```